# How to return Observable<String> based on the conditions of Observable<Bool> RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I'm quite new to RxSwift.

Is there any way I can create a function that will return Observable based on the conditions of two functions below

```
func isValidPassword(_ str: PublishSubject<String>) -> Observable<Bool> {
    return str.asObservable().map {
        validator.isValidPasswordRegex($0) && $0.count >= 8
    }
}



func isNotEmpty(_ str: PublishSubject<String>) -> Observable<Bool> {
    return str.asObservable().map {
        $0.count != 0
    }
}
```

This code below is just an example of what I'm trying to achieve, hoped you got the idea.

```
func someFunc(_ str:PublishSubject<String>) -> Observable<String> {
   if !isValidPassword(str){
      return "Not a valid password" //should return as an observable string
   }
   if isNotEmpty(str){
      return "String is not empty" //should return as an observable string
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want to achieve here but I think you should use `filter` operator and not `map`. In this way you don't change the type of the starting observable but you remove elements that don't respect your conditions.

```swift
func isValidPassword(_ str: String) -> Bool {
  validator.isValidPasswordRegex(str) && str.count >= 8
}

func someFunc(_ str: PublishSubject<String>) -> Observable<String> {
  str
    .filter(isValidPassword)
    .filter { !$0.isEmpty }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce you to `zip`... It allows you to combine multiple Observables.

```
func someFunc(_ str: Observable<String>) -> Observable<String> {
    Observable.zip(isValidPassword(str), isNotEmpty(str))
        .map { isValidPassword, isNotEmpty -> String in
            if !isValidPassword {
                return "Not a valid password"
            }
            if isNotEmpty {
                return "String is not empty"
            }
            return "" // you didn't specify what it should return here...
        }
}
```

Note that I updated the type signatures of your existing functions:

```
func isValidPassword(_ str: Observable<String>) -> Observable<Bool>
func isNotEmpty(_ str: Observable<String>) -> Observable<Bool>
```

Passing Subjects around like that is a recipe for disaster.

> Subjects provide a convenient way to poke around Rx, however they are not recommended for day to day use.
> -- [Introduction to Rx](http://introtorx.com/)

### UPDATE

I think the code would be better if you implemented like this though:

```
func errorMessage(text: Observable<String>) -> Observable<String> {
    text.map(errorMessage)
}

func errorMessage(_ str: String) -> String {
    if !isValidPassword(str) {
        return "Not a valid password"
    }
    if isNotEmpty(str) {
        return "String is not empty"
    }
    return ""
}

func isValidPassword(_ str: String) -> Bool
func isNotEmpty(_ str: String) -> Bool
```

It's much easier to test this way.